# large string in url as parameter carte pentaho

Tags: java, http, pentaho, kettle

Can I send a large string in url as parameter in carte url when calling a transformation that create a file as content is the string sent, 
i want something like:  https://cluster:cluster@[host]:[port]/kettle/executeTrans/trans=[repo_of_transf]/&filename=[my_small_string]&contentfile=[my_large_string] 
or there is another strategy that send in post method a big string with carte web service.

Comment: You cant sent lot of data using URL (Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters)

Comment: check this stuf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203686/how-can-i-deal-with-http-get-query-string-length-limitations-and-still-want-to-b

Comment: also I ask if there is a way to execute transformation with carte server and set parameters to carte in post method

Answer (score 2):

You should use POST method to pass long parameters

Comment: please how can i do it in pentaho kettle, particularly when sending this string in carte server??