# Is it correct to use POST call while fetching some resource without modifying the state of resource on server?

Tags: rest, http-post

I have some resources stored in database. Based on data requested by client, server should retrieve the data from db and return to client. But here client can send some data(like some row ids) which makes sense to have in request body instead of header. Is it fine to use POST method where data can be part of request body?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use query parameters? This is definitely a `GET` situation

Comment: Data in request can be too large to contain in query params.

Comment: According to the HTTP spec, there's no maximum length to a query string -- how long are we talking?

Comment: Its not just about length of data, data should not be exposed also.

Comment: This sounds like a design issue

Comment: I feel the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deal with HTTP GET query string length limitations and still want to be RESTful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203686/how-can-i-deal-with-http-get-query-string-length-limitations-and-still-want-to-b)